How to Send a List of Objects with MultipartFile[] and Metadata in a Single Request in Spring Boot
The official documentation describes what to do if you need to get both json and multipart data from a request:
@PostMapping("/")
public String handle(@RequestPart("meta-data") MetaData metadata,
        @RequestPart("file-data") MultipartFile file) {
    // ...
}

The official documentation describes what to do if I need to get both json and multipart data from a request. But what to do if i need an array of such objects?
Can we make something like this work:
public record Data(MetaData metadata, List<MultipartFile> files) {}

@PostMapping("/")
public String handle(Set<Data> data) {
    // ...
}

Is it even possible? Or maybe some kind of workaround?
And in the end how to test it using Postman?
UPDATE:
Here is a link for a small github repo to try it yourself real quick:
https://github.com/Panic7/question-demo-multipart
The logs of the issue:
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/", parameters={multipart}
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.demo.DataController#handle(List)
o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public java.lang.String com.example.demo.DataController.handle(java.util.List<com.example.demo.DataController$MetaDataDTO>): Required part 'data' is not present.
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'data' is not present.]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST

cULR:
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'data[0].metadata="{\"name\": \"example2\", \"description\": \"description2\"}"' \
--form 'data[0].files=@"/C:/Users/user/Pictures/images.jpg"'


First, define your data model.
public class MetaData {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    // Getters and setters
}

public record Data(MetaData metadata, List<MultipartFile> files) {}

In the controller method, use List to receive multiple Data objects. You can use @RequestPart annotation
@RestController
public class DataController {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String handle(@RequestPart("data") List<Data> data) {
        // 处理数据
        data.forEach(d -> {
            System.out.println("Metadata: " + d.metadata());
            d.files().forEach(f -> System.out.println("File: " + f.getOriginalFilename()));
        });
        return "Data received successfully";
    }
}

Testing with Postman
setting request
Request Type: Select POST.
URL: Set to your controller path, for example http://localhost:8080/.
Headers: Add Content-Type headers, set to multipart/form-data.
give a typical example:
Suppose you have two Data objects, each containing a MetaData and a file:
Key：data[0].metadata，Type：Text，Value：{"name": "example1", "description": "description1"}。
Key: data[0].files, Type: File, Value: select file1.txt.
Key：data[1].metadata，Type：Text，Value：{"name": "example2", "description": "description2"}。
Key: data[1].files, Type: File, Value: select file2.txt.
Click the Send button and you should see the console output MetaData and file information for each Data object.

Hi, thank you very much for your reply.
But unfortunately it doesn't work, I did everything as you said and still get a response with status 400.
I will update the description of the question with logs and attach a link to the git repo for a quick opportunity to try it yourself. Thanks!

sorry it didn't help,hope you resolve it oneday!
